# Normal distribution in Excel

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, excel

How do I calculate with Excel's formula to answer the question:

> What is the probability for a student's point is less than 560 by
>   using excel?

I know how to answer the question
- What is the probability for a student's point is higher than 620.
The answer is "=1 - NORM.DIST(620;590;25;true)".

Info:
Student's average is 590 and the standard deviation is 25

Comment: Welcome to the site! You cross-posed it [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508013/normal-distribution-with-less-probability). Please note that, according to the [help center](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), "cross-posting is not encouraged on SE sites. Choose one best location to post your question."

Answer (score 1):

=NORM.DIST(560,590,25,TRUE)

use commas, not semicolons

Comment: It should be `NORMDIST` rather than `NORM.DIST` in `Excel`.

Comment: works both ways

Comment: Thanks @Hotaka! I only checked it in `Excel 2007`. It turns out that `NORM.DIST` is the new function for `NORMDIST`.

Comment: I suspect there is a language difference as using `;` instead of `,` in Excel is an indication that $\frac12$ is written `1,5` rather than `1.5`

Comment: @Henry, thank goodness, you cross-posted your comment here. At least in `Excel 2007`, I tested `;` does not work. Also I suspect `1.5` can be coded as `1,5` in `Excel 2007`.

Comment: @Randel:  It does in Spanish editions of Excel and I suspect many others.  See [this](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/385317-semicolon-comma-regional.html) for a discussion